# How do I identify which YouTube videos I have watched?

Tags: jquery, youtube, greasemonkey

YouTube has broken its functionality to be able to remove videos I've seen and am subscribed to.

Now I want to implement such behavior myself using a GreaseMonkey script.

I'm still left without one problem, which is: How to identify whether I already clicked on a video?

- Can I simply remove all video boxes that contain a visited link (They are Purple)?
  <sub>This didn't work previous time I tried. Did I perhaps do something wrong?</sub>
- Should I rewrite the `a` tag so it calls my script and uses local storage?
- Is there a more easy method to do this?

Comment: @Brock: Nah... Implemented something with localStorage. Updating alex's answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Firefox (assuming using the Greasemonkey plugin) has nerfed the ability to see what links have been visited, because it violated the privacy of the end user. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector).
2. `localStorage` is definitely an option.

---

**Update by [Tom Wijsman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47064/tom-wijsman):**

```
$(function() {
    $('div#feed h4 a').each(function(index){
        var id = $(this).attr('href').split('v=')[1].split('&')[0];

        $(this).click(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('href').split('v=')[1].split('&')[0];
            localStorage.setItem('YT#' + id, '1');
        });

        if (localStorage.getItem('YT#' + id) == '1')
        {
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That's indeed why. It seemed fairly easy to implement. I've updated your answer with the code that I'm using now and works, the `parent()` part could still use some improvement but I most likely will not change that until it breaks... Thanks!

Comment: I tried it with Tampermonkey for chrome, but nothing changed. I wonder if it could be much different from that? Anyway, I actually wanted just to make the watched entry to shrink to a single line, but "I am sure?" that will be a lot more complex :)